# javascript to change style display

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a bunch of items setup with `<div id="first" class="source">`
I'm in Google Chrome, and when page loads it hides those items when I click the OnClick button it will un hide them, but I'm not able to click it again and make it hide.

HTML

```
<body onload="setup();">
<a  href="#first" onClick="shoh('first');" >
```

JS:

```
function setup() {
  foo = document.getElementById('first');
  foo = document.getElementsByClassName('source');
  for (c=0; c<foo.length; c++) {
    foo[c].style.display='none'
  }
}


function shoh(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'){
    var divs = document.getElementById(id);
    for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) { 
      divs[i].style.display='block'
    }
  } else {
    cow = document.getElementById(id);
    for(a=0; a<cow.length; a++) { 
      cow[a].style.display='none'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Grammar police have arrived at the scene. Please wait.

Comment: You don't need to iterate through your `nodes` when using `document.getElementById()`. just set it: `document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'WHATEVER'`

Comment: To make the *shoh* function generic, don't set `style.display = 'block'`, use `style.display = ''` so that the element returns to its default or inherited display value.

Comment: If your using any framework or extension for js they usually have a toggle function you can just run 

otherwise check the answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issue here:

If you compare two variables you need to use `==`, so therefore it should be:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'
```

Also, you are using `getElementById`, which returns a single node, not an array.  So therefore you should not loop over the returned value:

```
var div = document.getElementById(id);
div.style.display='block';
```

So in the end, it should look like this:

```
function shoh(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    div.style.display='block';
  } else {
    cow = document.getElementById(id);
    cow.style.display='none';
  }
}
```

Comment: This appears to work but only for the first item in my array.  Would I need to go with document.getElementsByClassName  and if i do that would i need to loop?

Comment: You can't have more than one item with the same `id` on your page. If you do `getElementsByClassName('first')` you would not find your `<div id="first">` element.

Answer (score 3):

Your conditional isn't doing a comparison. You need to change

```
if (document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'){
```

to

```
if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none'){
```